# Producer Consumer with shared queue C

Tags: c, multithreading

I was able to resolve the deadlock in my code and it works as it should for 1 producer and 1 consumer. However, if I introduce more than 1 requester thread I seem to be printing several copies of the same line to results.txt. In fact its prints as many copies of the same line as there are requester threads, which is weird. I think it comes down to either one of my exit conditions is off, or my resolver function is not thread safe for multiple threads. Ive checked my exit conditions and they seem ok to me.

I think I am running multiple requester threads on the same input file. I need to ensure that each requester thread only accesses one input file at a time,

.h file

```
#ifndef MULTILOOKUP_H_
#define MULTILOOKUP_H_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "/home/user/Desktop/PA3/util.c"

#define MAX_REQUESTER_THREADS 10
#define MAX_RESOLVER_THREADS 5
#define MAX_INPUT_FILES 10
#define MAXSIZE 20

struct arguments {
        struct queue *q;
        char *input[MAX_INPUT_FILES];
        char *resLog;
        char *reqLog;
        char line[100];
        char result[100];
        char ipv6[100];
        int numInputFiles;
};

struct node {
    char name[100];
    struct node *next;
};

struct queue {
    int size;
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
};

void init(struct queue *);
void pop(struct queue *);
void push(struct queue *, char *);
void* requesterThread(void *);
void* resolverThread(void *);


pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t empty, full;


#endif
```

.c file

```
#include "multilookup.h"

/*----------------------Struct Functions------------------------*/
void init(struct queue *q) {
q->head = NULL;
q->tail = NULL;
q->size = 0;

}

void pop(struct queue *q)
{
if (q->size > 0) {
    q->size--;
    struct node *tmp = q->head;
    q->head = q->head->next;
    free(tmp);  
} else {
    return;
}    
}


void push(struct queue *q, char *name)
{
if (q->size < MAXSIZE) {
    q->size++;
    if (q->head == NULL) {
        q->head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        strcpy(q->head->name, name);
        q->head->next == NULL;
        q->tail = q->head;
    } else {
        q->tail->next = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        strcpy(q->tail->next->name, name);
        q->tail->next->next = NULL;
        q->tail = q->tail->next;
    }
} else {
    return;
}   
}
/*--------------------------End of struct functions------------------*/

void* requesterThread(void *receivedStruct) {
    struct arguments *args_ptr;
    args_ptr = (struct arguments*) receivedStruct;

    FILE *fptr;
    FILE *sptr;
    int fileCounter = 0;

    if ((sptr = fopen(args_ptr->reqLog, "w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Bogus output path.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

        //Read from input file and push to shared queue
    while (1) {
        if ((fptr = fopen(args_ptr->input[fileCounter], "r")) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error! Bogus input file path.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        //Go through each file one at a time
        while (fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]%*c", args_ptr->line) != EOF) {
                       
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
            while (args_ptr->q->size == MAXSIZE) {
                pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &mutex);
            }

            push(args_ptr->q, args_ptr->line);

            pthread_cond_signal(&full);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

            fprintf(sptr, "%s \n", args_ptr->line);

            fprintf(sptr, "Thread %lu serviced %d file(s)\n", pthread_self(), fileCounter + 1);
    }

    fileCounter++;
    //Condition to send poisonPill to consumer
    if(fileCounter == args_ptr->numInputFiles) {
        push(args_ptr->q, NULL);
        break;
    }

}
fclose(fptr);
fclose(sptr);

return 0;
}


void* resolverThread(void *receivedStruct) {
        struct arguments *args_ptr;
        args_ptr = (struct arguments *) receivedStruct;

        FILE *rptr;

        if( (rptr = fopen(args_ptr->resLog, "w")) == NULL) {
               fprintf(stderr, "Error! Bogus output file path.\n");
               exit(1);
        }

        while(1) {
             pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
             while (args_ptr->q->size == 0) {
                 pthread_cond_wait(&full, &mutex);
             }

             strcpy(args_ptr->result, args_ptr->q->head->name);
             pop(args_ptr->q);

             pthread_cond_signal(&empty);
             pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);


             if (args_ptr->result != NULL && args_ptr->q->size > 0) {
                    if (dnslookup(args_ptr->result, args_ptr->ipv6, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN) == -1){
                         fprintf(stderr, "Bogus hostname.\n");
                         fprintf(rptr, "%s, \n", args_ptr->result);
                     } else {
                         fprintf(rptr, "%s, %s\n", args_ptr->result, args_ptr->ipv6);
                     }
             } else {break;}
        }
 fclose(rptr);
 return 0;
}


int main(/*int argc, char *argv[]*/) {

pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&empty, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&full, NULL);

int num_req_threads;
int num_res_threads;
int rc1;
int rc2;

char *inputFiles[] = {"/home/user/Desktop/PA3/input/names1.txt", "/home/user/Desktop/PA3/input/names2.txt"}; //argv[5];

//instance of shared queue struct
struct queue q;
init(&q);

//instance of arguments struct
struct arguments args;

args.q = &q;
for (int i = 0; i < MAXINPUT; i++) {
    args.input[i] = inputFiles[i];//argv[5];
}
args.reqLog = "/home/user/Desktop/PA3/serviced.txt";//argv[3];
args.resLog = "/home/user/Desktop/PA3/results.txt"; //argv[4];
args.numInputFiles = 2;

num_req_threads = 1;
num_res_threads = 1;

if (num_req_threads > MAX_REQUESTER_THREADS) {
    printf("Cannot have more than 10 requester threads!\n"); exit(1);}
if (num_res_threads > MAX_RESOLVER_THREADS) {
    printf("Cannot have more than 5 requester threads!\n"); exit(1);}

//Thread Creation
pthread_t reqThreads[num_req_threads];
pthread_t resThreads[num_res_threads];

for(int i = 0; i < num_req_threads; i++) {
    rc1 = pthread_create(&reqThreads[i], NULL, requesterThread, (void *)&args);
    printf("Requester thread %d created.\n", i);
}
for (int j = 0; j < num_res_threads; j++) {
    rc2 = pthread_create(&resThreads[j], NULL, resolverThread, (void *) &args);
    printf("Resolver thread %d created.\n", j);
}
if(rc1 || rc2) {
    printf("Could not create threads.\n");
    exit(-1);
}
for (int m = 0; m < num_req_threads; m++) {
    pthread_join(reqThreads[m], 0);
}
for (int n = 0; n < num_res_threads; n++) {
    pthread_join(resThreads[n], 0);
}

pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
pthread_cond_destroy(&empty);
pthread_cond_destroy(&full);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation to make the code readable.

Comment: What is the purpose of the dnslookup at line 123?  Your code looks a little bit suspicious.

Comment: Now this code is seg-faulting when i declare args_ptr. I changed nothing in my code, but when I went to run it this morning it started seg-faulting when I declare args_ptr in requesterThread and resolverThread functions. Why is this?